# How to use errno the same way in C++11 as it was in C++03

Tags: c++

Trying to understand :

> C.2.9 Clause 19: diagnostics library [diff.cpp03.diagnostics]
> 19.4
>
> Change: Thread-local error numbers
>
> Rationale: Support for new thread facilities.
>
> Effect on original feature: Valid but implementation-specific C++ 2003 code that relies on errno being the same across threads may change behavior in this International Standard.

I understand `<error.h>` content is in header `<cerrno>` but we have to define `errno` as a macro. Can anyone explain what we can do so that `errno` would act the same way as it was in C++03 during multi-threading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 us the first official standard that has a notion of multi-threading. This implies that if you use multiple threads in C++03 or C++98 you are using undefined behavior.

The whole idea about this change is about the following code:

```
functionThatSetsErrNo();
if (errno == something)
    ...
```

If you run this code and the execution results in functionThatSetsErrNo of thread 1, followed by functionThatSetsErrNo of thread 2, followed by the if-statements these if-statements do the right thing in C++11 and gave you a race condition in C++03 possibly combined with the `errno` of the second execution.

So what did change? If you after calling functionThatSetsErrNo started a thread, that thread no longer can read the `errno` value. Or similarly, if you have synchronization between threads and one calls the function and the other reads `errno`.

I hope this indicates that this change ain't too much to worry about as this delayed requesting of `errno` is something that is barely done and relying on transfer over threads is even done less.

If you do end up with this situation, you need to put a global `std::atomic` in your program and after execution assign `errno` into it while reading it from another thread. Although, I actually would recommend getting rid of such strange behavior.

Answer (score 4):

You don’t need to change anything.

The change in the standard is purely because C++03 had no notion of threads, and the abstract machine model used by the standard to describe the semantics of standard C++ code needed to be updated for C++11 to support threads.

But the observable behaviour of `errno` in conforming C++ code stayed roughly the same, with the sole exception that `errno` is now defined thread-locally, and if your code assumes that the value of `errno` is the same across threads it will break.

Comment: So you are saying we can use errno as it is with "error.h" no need to define it as macro? I got it, errno will break only if code is trying to get error message across threads as well. But if we want keep that thing same, can we? .

Comment: @alearner Yes, just include the header, don’t try to define `errno` yourself.

Comment: @alearner you could create a `std::atomic<int> latest_errno;` that you set after each call that might change `errno`, like `latest_errno = errno;`